# Cant use javascipt in browser

Tags: jxbrowser

i.m use jxbrowser
Need call browser.executeJavaScript("document.title = 'My title';");
method executeJavaScript not found

version 7.12

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.browser.Browser;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.Engine;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.engine.EngineOptions;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.BrowserView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the corresponding JxBrowser documentation at https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/javascript.html#executing-javascript

According to the documentation, in order to execute JavaScript use the following approach:

```
browser.mainFrame().ifPresent(frame -> 
        frame.executeJavaScript("document.title = 'My title';"));
```

More examples you can find at https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-Examples